# VB code equivalent to C# for declaring struct

Tags: c#, vb.net, struct

I'm currently migrating some VB.Net code to C#, and am quite confused about the `struct` in VB.NET.

Here is the code from VB which I would like to ask the equivalent in C# or some explanation.

Below is the `struct` format

```
struct Pt_Appt
{
    public Pt_Appt(int pID, int aID)
    {
        PatientID = pID;
        AppointID = aID;
    }
    public int PatientID;
    public int AppointID;
}
```

Below is the code that is confusing me, I've tried and it seems creating array of `struct` but why negative value.

```
Dim pt_appts(-1) As pt_appt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It declares an empty array of type `pt_appt`. The upper bound is set to `-1`. Since the lower bound is always `0`, this results in no valid indices. Arrays are re-sized via `ReDim`. However, this should be avoided if possible. In most cases, a `List(Of T)` or similar structures are more appropriate.

The C# equivalent is

```
Pt_Appt[] pt_appts = new Pt_Appt[0];
```

Comment: Gonna note on that one, seems c# is more readable in handling struct, Thanks.

Comment: @user2058252 The fact that `Pt_appt` is a struct has nothing to do with the array initialization.  You can do the same thing in VB with a class or primitive type.

Comment: @DStanley been quite a long not doing vb.net seems I forgot that one.

Comment: Actually, the C# equivalent is Pt_Appt[] pt_appts = new Pt_Appt[0];  There is a difference between an uninitialized array (your C# code), and a zero-length array.  Your C# is the equivalent of Dim pt_appts() As Pt_Appt.

Comment: For structs which are used for the purpose of holding a few independent-but-related values together with duct tape, the semantics of an array are much superior to those of a `List<T>`.  For example, given `Structure PhoneNumber : Dim AreaCode, Exchange, Tail, Extension, As String : End Structure`, it would be possible to iterate through an array of such structure and update the area code field of items with certain area-code/exchange combinations without having to touch anything else.  With a list, it would be necessary to read each item, modify it, and then store it back.